Best Questions & Answers from 3rd Quarter of 2024
Here's the latest instalment in our quarterly best-post collections, the purpose of which is to gather some particularly good Literature Q&A in order to get some easily available links to showcase our site.
One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's community-run X account. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the third quarter (Jul/Aug/Sep) of 2024.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older best-of posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on the main site that's being nominated.)

When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on great questions with great answers, and perhaps also great unanswered questions (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - not anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
Remember that votes don't necessarily reflect quality, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
Ideally, some explanation of why the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.


Questions from 3q 2024

Answers from 3q 2024


b4rtr's answer to the question In Turgenev's "First Love", what did the father mean by “Vous devez vous séparer de cette”? is very detailed and uses arguments from several lectures on Turgenev's work.
verbose's answer to the question In what way were Stuart court masques examples of neoplatonic idealism? cites both contemporary sources (Ben Jonson and Philip Sidney) and some modern scholarship.


I would like to nominate two questions (and their answers).
The first is Is the white man on the other side of the Joliba river a historically identifiable person, a question Tsundoku asked about an incident in the book Ségou. Both Tsundoku and Clara Diaz Sanchez gave excellent answers identifying the man as the explorer Mungo Park.
The second is the question Who was the "Dutch" author, Bumstone Bumstone, asked by Mikado. I was able to answer that one ... the book Mikado was asking about contained the line

He used to read Ibsen and that other Dutch author—Bumstone Bumstone, isn't it.

I reasoned that Ibsen and "Bumstone Bumstone" likely had the same nationality, so I looked through Wikipedia's list of Norwegian authors, and the author Bjørnstjerne Bjørnson was clearly the correct author.
